# starting and ending balance for specific month in sql

Tags: sql-server, sh

lets take date range from 1/10/2014  to 31/10/2014 and data is referenced below

remembered i want starting and ending balances for month october in sql

```
+------------+-----------+----------+---------+
| actualdate |  linecost |  balance |  lineid |
+------------+-----------+----------+---------+
| 1/10/2014  |   100     |    250   |    73   |
| 14/10/2014 |   50      |    350   |    74   |
| 15/10/2014 |   200     |    450   |    75   |
| 18/10/2014 |   300     |    550   |    76   |
+------------+-----------+----------+---------+
```

output should be like this!

Month      startingbalance      endingbalance

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP BY` and `DATENAME()`.

### Query

```
SELECT DATENAME(mm,actualDate) AS [Month],
MIN(balance) AS startingbalance,
MAX(balance) AS endingbalance
FROM tbl
GROUP BY DATENAME(mm,actualDate);
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae72f/3)

Comment: sorry     50,20,90,10   then what

Comment: It will return the minimum and maximum value.

Comment: value from first index as opening balance and value from last index as closing balance

Comment: what if i have different months coz with this query it doesn,t give me exact answer for closing balance for different month

Comment: You want first value as startingbalance and last value for endingbalance rite?

Comment: yeah but for different months

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH(ACTUAL_DATE)), MIN(BALANCE), MAX(BALANCE)
FROM TABLE_NAME
GROUP BY MONTH(ACTUAL_DATE)
```

This might be helpful ty you.

Answer (score 0):

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl(actualDate DATETIME,lineCost INT,balance INT,lineid INT);

INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('2014-10-01 01:02:03',10,10,73);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('2014-10-14 01:03:10',10,20,74);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('2014-10-15 01:04:20',5,5,75);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('2014-10-18 01:05:30',3,1,76);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('2014-10-18 01:06:20',4,2,77);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('2014-10-18 01:07:10',6,100,78);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('2014-10-18 02:08:00',7,200,79);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('2014-10-18 03:09:50',8,150,80);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('2014-10-19 04:01:50',9,160,81);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('2014-10-20 05:09:50',11,170,82);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('2014-10-20 06:09:50',12,180,83);
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES('2014-10-20 07:29:40',50,380,84);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DATENAME(mm,actualDate) AS [Month],DATENAME(yyyy,actualDate) AS [YEAR],
(SELECT balance FROM tbl WHERE actualDate=(SELECT MIN(actualDate) FROM tbl)) AS startingbalance,
(SELECT balance FROM tbl WHERE actualDate=(SELECT MAX(actualDate) FROM tbl)) AS endingbalance
FROM tbl
GROUP BY DATENAME(mm,actualDate),DATENAME(yyyy,actualDate)
```

**[Results][2]**:

```
|   MONTH | YEAR | STARTINGBALANCE | ENDINGBALANCE |
|---------|------|-----------------|---------------|
| October | 2014 |              10 |           380 |
```